# Missing "view more" link in user profile

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

On [this user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759019/cthulhu), the reputation panel only shows an entry for one post and it doesn't have a "view more" link like I see on other profiles. Is there a reason for this, or is it a bug?

I was expecting to see more post entries and the "view more" link instead of all this blank space:

> [image: screenshot of user reputation panel]

Comment: Post a link to the image.

Comment: @Oded this is wat i saw http://imgur.com/JeEzs

Comment: my question is why its not like your reputation tab ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "view more" link in the reputation summary only appears when there are more than four posts eligible to be shown in that summary box. In this case, there's only one post that the system considers eligible to be shown there, so there's no reason for the "view more" link.

This behavior is similar to all the other summary boxes. The boxes for answers, questions, and accounts will all show up to five, plus a "view more" link if there are more than five. The tags and badges boxes display up to ten, and the "view more" link if there are more than ten. Here's an [example account that has no "view more" links at all](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1643980/tuan-vu) (at least at the time of writing this).

I don't have any idea how the system determines what posts to show in that summary box; I don't believe it's ever been officially disclosed by SE. It can be fairly random, but you can always click on the reputation tab which is literally right above that summary - it takes you to the exact same page.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug to me, but, if you want to look at the rest of the entries in the mean time, you can click on the **Reputation** header, and that will bring you there